# arduino IDE code for 2 DC car with L298 and ultrasonic and bluetooth control with android

Tags: c++, xcode, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I want to make my car to move with the android and if distance 20cm to rotate. This is my code I've written:

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h" 
#include  "Ultrasonic.h"
 int distance = 0;
 int UltrasonicData;
 Ultrasonic ultrasonic (12,13);

const int IN1=3;
const int IN2=5;
const int IN3=6;
const int IN4=9;
 boolean Rotate=true;
 int BluetoothData;
 SoftwareSerial HC05(1,0); // RX, TX
 int  SPEED_Control=200;
 void setup() {

pinMode( IN1 ,OUTPUT);// Right Motor 1st wire
pinMode( IN2 ,OUTPUT);// Right Motor 2nd wire
pinMode( IN3 ,OUTPUT);// left Motor 1st wire
pinMode( IN4 ,OUTPUT);// left Motor 2nd wire
 HC05.begin(9600);
}
 void FORWARD(int Speed){


  analogWrite(IN1,0);
  analogWrite(IN2,Speed);
   analogWrite(IN3,Speed);
  analogWrite(IN4,0);
}
void BACKWARD(int Speed){
 //When we want to let Motor To Rotate Counter clock wise
 // just void this part on the loop section .
 analogWrite(IN1,Speed);
 analogWrite(IN2,0);
  analogWrite(IN3,0);
  analogWrite(IN4,Speed);
}
 void LEFT(int Speed){

 analogWrite(IN1,0);
  analogWrite(IN2,Speed);
 analogWrite(IN3,0);
 analogWrite(IN4,Speed);
}
 void RIGHT(int Speed){

 analogWrite(IN1,Speed);
 analogWrite(IN2,0);
 analogWrite(IN3,Speed);
  analogWrite(IN4,0);
}

void Stop(){

 analogWrite(IN1,0);
 analogWrite(IN2,0);
 analogWrite(IN3,0);
 analogWrite(IN4,0);
}

 void loop() {

if(ultrasonic.available()){
UltrasonicData=ultrasonic.read();
Serial.println(ultrasonic);}
distance=ultrasonic.Ranging(CM);
       Rotate=!Rotate ;// Random direction

      if(UltrasonicData<=20 &&Rotate==true ){
        RIGHT(120);
     }
      if(UltrasonicData<=20 &&Rotate==false){
         LEFT(120);
     }
  if (HC05.available()){
 BluetoothData=HC05.read();
Serial.println(BluetoothData);

 if(BluetoothData=='F'){   // if number 1 pressed .... 
  FORWARD(SPEED_Control);
  }
  if(BluetoothData=='B'){   // if number 1 pressed .... 
  BACKWARD(SPEED_Control);
  }
  if(BluetoothData=='L'){   // if number 1 pressed .... 
   RIGHT(SPEED_Control);

  }
   if(BluetoothData=='R'){   // if number 1 pressed ....
   LEFT(SPEED_Control);
   }
    if(BluetoothData=='S'){   // if number 1 pressed ....
   Stop();
   }
   if(BluetoothData=='0'){  SPEED_Control=0 ;}//Speed 
   if(BluetoothData=='1'){  SPEED_Control=50; }//Speed 
   if(BluetoothData=='2'){  SPEED_Control=100; }//Speed 
   if(BluetoothData=='3'){  SPEED_Control=120; }//Speed 
   if(BluetoothData=='4'){  SPEED_Control=140; }//Speed 
   if(BluetoothData=='5'){  SPEED_Control=160; }//Speed 
   if(BluetoothData=='6'){  SPEED_Control=180; }//Speed 
   if(BluetoothData=='7'){  SPEED_Control=200; }//Speed 
   if(BluetoothData=='8'){  SPEED_Control=220; }//Speed 
   if(BluetoothData=='9'){  SPEED_Control=240; }//Speed 
   if(BluetoothData=='q'){  SPEED_Control=255; }//Speed   
  }
 }
```

Problem: I get the following error

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:81:12: note: 
>   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized your Serial monitor.

```
Serial.begin(9600)
```

Or whatever baud rate you want.